# change the no result to nearest in match select2

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, json, jquery-select2

I would like to get the closest match to a postcode in select2. If the user types in DE2, but if the user tries to type in the rest of there postcode so say DE20BE, the 'BE' will not displayed (there is a limit of 4 currently set) but can it match to the closest to DE20 so say DE2, at the moment it comes back with No Results, code below, I think I would need to not allow spaces?:

Here is my MySQL query:

```
SELECT `postcode` FROM `postcodes` WHERE `postcode` LIKE '%?%' ORDER BY `postcode` LIMIT 0,50;
```

Here the JSON result:

```
[{"ok":1,"text":"DE1"},{"ok":1,"text":"DE11"},{"ok":1,"text":"DE12"},{"ok":1,"text":"DE13"},{"ok":1,"text":"DE14"},{"ok":1,"text":"DE15"}]
```

Here is the JS:

```
var item = [];
function postCodeAjaxAutoComplete(element, url) {
        $(element).select2({
            placeholder: "Select a Postcode Area (E10)",
            minimumInputLength: 1,
            maximumInputLength: 4,
            multiple: false,
            id: function(e) { return e.text; },
            ajax: {
                url: url,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: function(term, page) {

                    return {
                        q: term
                    };
                },
                results: function (data, page) {
                    return { results: data };
                }
            },
            formatResult: formatResult,
            formatSelection: formatSelection,
            initSelection: function(element, callback) {
                var data = [];
                $(element.val().split(",")).each(function(i) {
                    data.push({
                        text: item[0]
                    });
                });
                callback(data);
            }
        });
    };
    postCodeAjaxAutoComplete('#ajax-postcode', '/ajax.php?do=postcode');

    function formatResult(data) {
        return data.text;
    };

    function formatSelection(data) {
        return data.text;
    };
```

Comment: How did we get from user typing `DE1` to returning a result starting `DE20`?

Comment: My bad sorry I rushed typing the post I will update the post.

Comment: I don't know the system in your country, but performing partial matches on postal codes in the UK can yield strange results (for example, `DE2` could be considerably closer to `DE7`, `CM4` or `XY10` than `DE20`).  It's usually better to determine distance through a geodesic search, such as using the Haversine formula against the latitude/longitude coordinates of the user's search and known locations.

Comment: Ok thanks for your reply, yes the database is a UK postcode search. The search is on the string typed not on the Geo Location the field in the database only has between 3-4 characters if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69065/4/1)

```
SET @search = "DE20";

SELECT `postcode`,
   (SUBSTRING(CONCAT(@search,'^^^^'),1,1)=SUBSTRING(postcode,1,1)) +
   (SUBSTRING(CONCAT(@search,'^^^^'),2,1)=SUBSTRING(postcode,2,1)) +
   (SUBSTRING(CONCAT(@search,'^^^^'),3,1)=SUBSTRING(postcode,3,1)) +
   (SUBSTRING(CONCAT(@search,'^^^^'),4,1)=SUBSTRING(postcode,4,1)) as matches
FROM `postcodes` 
HAVING matches > 0
ORDER BY matches DESC,LENGTH(postcode),postcode LIMIT 0,50;
```

Comment: Works exactly how I wanted it to thanks! Haven't seen some of this syntax before.

Comment: I am just adding the ^ to the end of your search string so that if your search string is only 3 characters long and the postcode is also 3 characters long we won't get getting a match because `^` is not equal to a blank. that's all you can use any character other than ^ so long as you know it's not ever  going to be in your postcode

Comment: Ah ok, I removed your @search and done a prepare query '?' after, seem to work well, changed the results to 30 to cut down on load also. Thanks again!